# CSS3 3D webkit issue

Tags: css, webkit, css-transitions, css-transforms

I have created a fiddle for my problem here http://jsfiddle.net/aakashgoel/ZcF4N/

The 3D rendering works fine in Mozilla Firefox but fails in Google Chrome. Which of the properties used in there are not supported by Chrome?

Edit: Expected Result: Click on the box '1' to flip it. It should change to 2 with a blue background.

Edit: This is what chrome outputs: 
[image: chrome rendering.]

Comment: Seems to be working fine for me in Win7 using Chrome 20.0.1096.1 Which version of Chrome are you seeing a problem in?

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu Chrome 18.0.1025.162

Comment: For me it works ok in Chrome but not i Firefox... it makes some visual glitches

Comment: works here; Chrome 18.0.1025.151 Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: Yuval: same here! now that is weird! I have attached the screenshot on how **my** chrome shows it!

Comment: Works fine here: Chrome 18.0.1025.142 Ubuntu 11.10

Comment: There was a bug in Chrome 16 that broke implicit z-ordering - this was subsequently fixed - perhaps it's that bug (if you're on Chrome 16?)

Comment: What happens if you type about:gpu into the address bar? Are all the ‘Graphics feature status’ items green?

Comment: Robin: yeah now I get the issue. But why only in Chrome? On the same hardware works fine in Firefox though. Here is what the about:gpu reads = >                                          `Graphics Feature Status
Canvas: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
HTML Rendering: Software only, hardware acceleration unavailable
3D CSS: Unavailable. Hardware acceleration unavailable
WebGL: Unavailable. Hardware acceleration unavailable
WebGL multisampling: Unavailable. Hardware acceleration unavailable`

Answer (score 0):

At this time Google Chrome does not have the full CSS3 module implemented. Perspective does not work, its just a "pseudo" 3d implementation. 3d props like translate3d or rotate3d will work only on X and Y but not on Z axis. Your example will work only in latest Firefox and Safari (also Webkit as Chrome).

Comment: Mircea: apparently perspective works just fine in latest builds of chrome. My build of chrome doesn't seem to have 3D CSS, WebGL available.

Comment: To see if Chrome really supports 3d please check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/dqWUN/1/ in latest Safari, Firefox and Chrome. Do you see the same thing?